# Calling AWS web services using extracted HTTP auth headers from Web Console session, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID not provided, so AWS client not available

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I got into a situation working for a client which does not provide in any way AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID as security protection. We have only available for development AWS Web Console. So I started searching for another way of the programmatic script(speed-up) my dev tasks.

Note: we cannot use AWS client without AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and secret.

My assumptions: If the AWS web console can do the same thing as aws cli (.eg create bucket, load data into bucket, etc.), why not use web console auth mechanism (visible in http request headers) and bind it to aws cli (or some other api call code) to make it work even without aws keys?

Question: Is this possible? For sure I can see in http headers following artifacts:

aws-session-token
aws-session-id
awsccc
and dozen of others...

My idea is to automate this by:

1. Go to the web console and login have a script that will
   automatically output from browser session required parameters to
   some text file
2. Use this extracted information by some dev script

If this is not supported or impossible to achieve with aws cli, can I use some SDK or raw AWS Api calls with extracted information?

I can extract SAML content which has above mentioned aws-creds header also I see oauth client call with following headers:

```
https://signin.aws.amazon.com/oauth?
client_id=arn%3Aaws%3Asignin%3A%3A%3Aconsole%2Fcanvas&
code_challenge=bJNNw87gBewdsKnMCZU1OIKHB733RmD3p8cuhFoz2aw&
code_challenge_method=SHA-256&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Ffromtb%3Dtrue%26isauthcode%3Dtrue%26state%3DhashArgsFromTB_us-east-1_c63b804c7d804573&
X-Amz-Security-Token=hidden content&
X-Amz-Date=20211223T054052Z&
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&
X-Amz-Credential=ASIAVHC3TML26B76NPS4%2F20211223%2Fus-east-1%2Fsignin%2Faws4_request&
X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&
X-Amz-Signature=3142997fe7212f041ef90c1a87288f53cecca9236098653904bab36b17fa53ef
```

Can I use it with AWS SDK somehow?

Comment: Its probably possible, but definitely risky and ill advised. The console is not an official API, so theres no guarantee it wont change over time breaking your system. Can you elaborate on your clients requirements (no aws keys?) and what your are trying to achieve? I strongly suspect there is a better way than hacking the console.

Comment: thx for response. So during development of S3 buckeets I need to reset buckets in dev env to original state during testing ETL jobs, imagine they don't work as expecting, so I need to masivelly clean up multiple ETL staging areas. In console i need to go to variety of subdirectories and delete files or directories (keys). Later I need to upload fresh content elsewhere. With console it will take minutes to tens of minutes, with script it will take seconds or tens of seconds. AWS keys distribution is simply prohibited by security department for this client. There are other cases i need script.

Answer (score 1):

To reset an S3 bucket to a known state, I would suggest looking at the AWS cli s3 sync command and the -delete switch. Create a "template" bucket with your default contents, then sync that bucket into your Dev Bucket to reset your Dev bucket.

As for your key problems, i would look at IAM Roles rather trying to hack the console auth.

As to how to run the AWS CLI, you have several options. It can be done from Lambda, ECS (containers running on your own Ec2) or an ec2 instance. All 3 allow you to attach an IAM role. That role can have policies attached (for your S3 bucket) - but there is no key to manage.

Comment: Thx a lot for initiative, but as stated I cannot use AWS client as we don't have AWS access keys available, I ask for scripting automation over console interface.

Comment: The above does not use AWS access keys - IAM Roles generate temporary credentials on demand - this is similar but different to IAM users with access keys (and generally gets past security teams without much issue). This is the AWS recommended solution to managing access without actually having to generate keys and manage them yourself. Also, technically `X-Amz-Credential` and `X-Amz-Security-Token` are temporary keys so your suggested solution breaks your requirements. If you need to use AWS services, you need to use access keys, or temporary credentials in one form or another.

Comment: aha, thx a lot for this, going to try.

Comment: The issue is I don't understand the content and the flow, but of course I first analysed traffic. Finally I found solution

Answer (score 1):

Thx for feedback to @MisterSmith! It kinda helped with follow up.

I have found also SAML call during analysis of Chrome traffic from login page to AWS console, I have found this project: https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws#linux

Which extracted all ~/.aws/credentials variables needed for aws cli to work.